# Dynamically increase SQL Column length

Tags: database, database-schema

Is there a way to dynamically increase Database Column length if an incoming data is larger than the length specified. Which database software can handle this ? Or is it something that needs to be handled by the application that inserts this data into the database ?

Comment: Most Databases have Fixed Column widths at time of creation. Why not create or update the column with the maximum length that you would envision. Are you referring to character fields? or Blobs?

Comment: The thought of the application changing schema on the fly fills me with terror. You don't want to do that! You can break many other things. Database struture needs to be correctly designed when it is created as it is much more problematic to change later. You should specify a length that will work for all likely incoming data. You need to analyze this type Of thing when designing a table (which is BTW why it's a bad idea to let an ORM design for you; it can't think about future needs). Database design takes forethought. NEVER allow applications to design or alter table structures dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I support @Ed Mendez and @HLGEM that you shouldn't do this but still if you want to do this then you should write a [Procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx) to do this. You should check the column size with `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_schema = DATABASE() AND   -- name of your database
      table_name = 'table_name' AND        -- name of your table
      column_name = 'name_of_column'     -- name of the column` in IF condition and then ALTER the table with ALTER Query. But while checking again in Procedure you will have to take care of input size. So better you can go for VARCHAR. If still you are unable to do please give the demo of your column I'll write the procedure code. Hope this help you.